# WPF Gridview - Is there a way to set tab order by column

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a ListView containing a GridView in XAML. I am trying to allow tab advancement through each item by column. That way the user can tab through each ListView item with a single column getting keyboard focus each time. I have messed around with setting different combinations of `KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Cycle"` for the listview and binding/setting the TabIndex properties of the DataTemplates withing the items/columns but nothing has worked.

Is there a way to do this in XAML or with attached properties? If not, are there any suggestions on how I might be able to architect an implementation of GridView to achieve something like this?

Comment: If I follow your question. The listview is intended as a lightweight display control. The datagrid is more suitable for editing and has a built in concept of a row you're editing. You can tab from one cell to the next left to right. It also responds to up and down arrows. Is this not suitable for whatever your requirement is?

Comment: Yes, I have used datagrid extensively. It seemed overkill for the task I'm trying to achieve...besides, I'm not sure that it would be any easier to achieve what I'm looking for with an off-the-shelf datagrid anyway.  It's basically a list of textboxes that must be filled out by the user. However, from a UX standpoint it makes much more sense to enter the same field for each item consecutively. Think barcode scanning; Enter all the IDs, then go back in and type in hand-entered data. In that case, you want it to advance through each column separately.

Comment: And I am using gridview to keep the column widths between items synced up and auto-sized.

Comment: However, I am thinking that the easiest solution to this problem might just be to use multiple listviews, one for each field, and put them in a grid. XAML won't be as concise but won't need any custom code...

Comment: Not sure i follow your description. Would an itemscontrol with a wrappanel as itemspanel do what you want?